# What is the css selector for a nephew?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a series of elements with the following html format:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="hoverArea"> ... </div>
   <div class="caption"> ... </div>
   <div class="image"> ... </div>
</div>
```

with .hoverArea, .caption, .image { position: absolute; }

When user hovers over the 'hoverArea' the (sibling) image enlarges with:

.hoverArea:hover ~ .image { width: 300px; }

This worked fine, but I now need to put the image in a parent/wrapper

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="hoverArea"> ... </div>
   <div class="caption"> ... </div>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="image"> ... </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

What is the selector I need for the nephew?
I thought it was just:

.hoverArea:hover  .image { width: 300px; }

Or

.wrap.hoverArea:hover .parent.image { ... }

But these doesnt seem to work.

And would it be any different if I was to add the parent with a '::before'?

Comment: `.hoverArea:hover ~ .parent .image`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator your selector do not work because the .image is not inside of hoverArea. Use the general sibling selector to find .parent and the image inside on hover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

`~` : for sibling selector 
`>` : for child selector 
In Sentence, `.hoverArea`'s sibling is `.parent` and it's child is `.image`

```
.hoverArea:hover ~ .parent > .image{
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Excellent - That's the first time I've seen an understandable explanation of how to traverse a hierarchy - thanks VERY much @Shashank Gb

Comment: @user801347 If it is the solution you are looking for, then accept it. It will be considered as solved [for more info] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)